# Как написать простую функцию?

Tags: php

```
function mobile(){
    $mobiles = array("iPhone","iPod","Android");
    foreach( $mobiles as $mobile ) {

    }
}
```

Как теперь с помощью **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']** проверить: есть mobile - cделать одно, а если не mobile - то другое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет [preg_match](http://php.ru/manual/function.preg-match.html).
Вот само условие:

```
if(preg_match('/iPhone|iPad|Android/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    //Выполняем что-то важное
}
```

Получить паттерн из массива можно [так](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php):

```
$pattern = '/' . implode('|', $mobiles) . '/i';
```

Тогда, соответственно, его нужно будет вставить вместо `'/iPhone|iPad|Android/i'`.

Что получится в итоге:

```
function mobile(...){
    ...
    $mobiles = array("iPhone","iPod","Android"); //если массив не будет меняться извне, можно сразу записать паттерн как '/iPhone|iPad|Android/i'
    $pattern = '/' . implode('|', $mobiles) . '/i'; //иначе строим паттерн из массива

    if(preg_match($pattern, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
        //Выполняем что-то важное
    }
}
```

**Обновление**
Минимальная по коду функция, удовлетворяющая Вашим требованиям:

```
function isMobile()
{
    return preg_match('/iPhone|iPad|Android/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}
```

Применение

```
if(!isMobile()) //если не мобильник
{
    //показываем 
}
```

Comment: @A1essandro собственно я хочу сделать функцию для вывода рекламного блока. Если зашел пользователь с телефона - не показываем, а если с компьютера - то показываем. А теперь скажите, пожалуйста, разумно ли использовать $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] при таком подходе или есть способ проще?

Comment: @rodion, ну лично я не встречал более простого способа. В обновлении ответа сделаю минимальную по коду функцию проверки.

Comment: @A1essandro спасибо.

Comment: @A1essandro еще уточнить хочу: прописывать нужно операционные системы?

Comment: @rodion Используйте готовое решение. К пример, [Mobile-Detect}(https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect), что только не умеет, а главное, любые нововведения (появления новых телефонов/планшетов/TV, возможно, в скором времени и бытовые чайники будут стучаться к Вам на сайт), будут там доступны. Этот проект достаточно популярен (более 4К звёзд), а значит, много людей (контрибьюторов) над ним работают.

**P.S. Откройте наконец для себя мир github, мир множества качественных и свободных решений. Не пишите свои велосипеды. Стыдитесь этого.**

Comment: @romeo как раз искал долгое время готовое решение, а потом прочитал про $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. Если честно, не знаю, зачем мне эта навороченная библиотека, если нужно всего-то скрыть рекламный блок.

Comment: @rodion

1. Это и близко не лежало с действительно навороченными библиотеками
2. Заданный вопрос решается до сих пор, а внешняя библиотека решила бы вопрос за пять минут
3. И, наконец, в чем проблема использования сторонней библиотеки? Сделает сайт медленнее на 5% (на самом деле еще меньше(? На целых 10-30 миллисекунд?